# Using Poisson's integral formula

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, problem-solving

The problem asks to prove the following equality using Poisson's integral formula (or [Poisson kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel), if I understood correctly from Wikipedia):

> $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{\cos \phi}\cos(\sin\phi)}{5-4\cos(\theta-\phi)}d\phi=\frac{2\pi}{3}e^{\cos \theta}\cos(\sin\theta)$$

The Poisson formula that is on the book is:

> $$f(re^{i\theta})=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{R^2-r^2}{R^2-2Rr\cos(\theta-\phi)+r^2}f(Re^{i\phi}) d\phi$$
>   If we consider the circule defined by $|z|=R$, and a point $z=re^{i\theta}$ inside of it.

Onto the problem, I have no idea how to do it. I guess from the RHS we get: $$f(re^{i\theta})=\frac{e^{\cos \theta}\cos(\sin\theta)}{3}$$
and from the numerator in the LHS:
$$(R^2-r^2)f(Re^{i\phi})=e^{\cos \phi}\cos(\sin\phi)$$

This problem has too many unknowns, how am I suppose to solve this? The problem doesn't give the value of $R$, and $r$ obviously depends on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want $5-4\cos (\theta-\phi) = R^2 - 2Rr\cos (\theta-\phi) + r^2$, that is, $R^2 + r^2 = 5$ and $2Rr = 4$. That makes $(R+r)^2 = R^2 + r^2 + 2Rr = 5+4 = 9$ and $(R-r)^2 = R^2+r^2-2Rr = 5-4 = 1$, so $R+r = 3$ and $R-r = 1$.

Further, it might be helpful to consider

$$e^{\cos \theta} \cos (\sin\theta) = \operatorname{Re} \left(e^{\cos\theta}(\cos(\sin\theta) + i\sin(\sin\theta))\right).$$

Comment: To get your result you seemed to get: $\frac{e^{\cos \theta}\cos(\sin\theta)}{3} = \frac{R^2-r^2}{R^2-2Rr\cos(\theta-\phi)+r^2}$,  then after getting the integrand to $\operatorname{Re} \left(e^{\cos\theta}(\cos(\sin\theta) + i\sin(\sin\theta))\right).$,to calculate the closed from of the integral could you just use the Cauchy Integral Formula ?

Comment: @Zophikel No, these are different parts. We have $$\frac{1}{5 - 4 \cos (\theta - \phi)} = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{R^2 - r^2}{R^2 - 2Rr \cos (\theta - \phi) + r^2}$$ for $R = 2r$. That part is the Poisson kernel times a constant. The other part is the harmonic function. With $e^{\cos \phi}\cdot \cos (\sin \phi) = \operatorname{Re} e^{\cos \phi + i\sin \phi}$ we know that the other part of the integrand comes from a harmonic function, and then the Poisson integral formula says the integral is $\frac{2\pi}{3} f(re^{i\theta})$.

Comment: We can't immediately use Cauchy's integral formula, since the integral isn't of the form $\int\frac{h(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}\,d\zeta$ with a holomorphic $\zeta$, but we can rewrite it into that form and then apply Cauchy's formula.

Comment: Ok from your first comment, the other part of the integrand comes from a harmonic function since harmonic functions are holomorphic, so to set up the integral for calculation you just considered  $\operatorname{Re} \left(e^{\cos\theta}(\cos(\sin\theta) + i\sin(\sin\theta))\right).$